# How to change the output to the count of words?

Tags: java, output

How can i change the output from "my name is"  from {2=1 4=1} to >the number of words with the length of  2 is 1 and then on the next line the amount of word with the length of 4 is 1, like the output underneath:

```
     //You have typed the sentence: my name is
     //the number of words with the length of  2 is 1
     //the amount of word with the length of 4 is 1
```

**Basically how can I change '{2=2, 4=1}' to a sentence form?**

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Write your sentence please:");// prints out the first instruction.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //object initialisation.
    String line=" ";//declaration for letters(String) characters.
    //int max = 20; //declaration for number(int) characters.
    while((line=scan.nextLine())!=null) { //scanner instruction, get a line from the key board.

        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");// splits the words
        Map<Integer,Integer> tokensLength = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {// this line of code checks for what must be true to carry on.
            int length = tokens[i].length();

        if (tokensLength.containsKey(length))
            tokensLength.put(length, tokensLength.get(length) + 1);

        else 
            tokensLength.put(length, 1);
    }

    for (Integer length : new TreeSet<Integer>(tokensLength.keySet()))
        System.out.println("You have typed the sentence: " + line);//prints out what you have typed.
    System.out.println("The word length frequency of the sentence is " + tokensLength);//prints out the results
    }//End of scanner instruction
}//End of main
```

Thank you! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there a specific thing that you've tried? Where did you get stuck? Is this a homework question?

Comment: At the moment the output for 'my name is' is ''The word length frequency of the sentence is {2=2, 4=1}''. How can I change my output slightly to the form of output I described above?

Comment: Basically how can I change '{2=2, 4=1}' to a sentence form?

Answer (score 0):

Use that to iterate over the map and write nice sentences :)

```
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : tokensLength.entrySet()){           
    System.out.println("There are "+entry.getValue()+" words of length "+entry.getKey());
}
```